# Пожелание "ни пухи ни пера"

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, а как появилось пожелание "ни пуха ни пера" (и, кстати, нужна ли тут запятая?) и ответ на него? Если, как это сразу кажется, это пожелание охотникам, то получается, что им желают ничего не поймать. А сейчас это вообще стало пожеланием удачи, но к чему тогда такой не слишком вежливый ответ?
В общем, буду признателен за разъяснения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Появилось выражение действительно в среде охотников. Добытчику не желали удачи, чтобы не сглазить: если пожелать удачи прямо, то злые духи будут строить козни, а так они отстанут и охота будет удачной.